# How can I copy a private branch in a repository and ensure its privacy?

Tags: git, github

Context:
There's a private repository containing a branch within our company github account that we want to copy and begin work on. We want this branch to exist as a new repository that's also private.

How can I copy this branch to a new repository and ensure that it doesn't copy to my personal github exposing the sensitive data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by using the following steps:

1. Create the new_repo in github.
2. cd to your local copy of the old repo you want to extract from,
   which is  set up to track the old_branch that will become the
   new_repo's master.
3. $ git push git@github.com:accountname/new_repo +old_branch:master

Using the above steps will ensure that your log history is intact when you push the specified branch to the new repo. This will also ensure privacy just so long as you push to a private repository.

Answer (score 1):

@Wunderbread you need next steps to do it:

1. Create a new branch without history using --orphan flag (look at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---orphanltnewbranchgt)
2. Remove all sensitive data from your new branch and make commit
3. Add new remote with `git remote add <newrepo>` and push it to new repo (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#git-remote-emaddem)

to ensure your new branch doesn't have a history just look it with `git log`, you should see only 1 commit without any previous history where you add/remove sensitive data.